# dotnetopenauth: unsolicited assertion only works with a dotnetopenauth relying party

Tags: dotnetopenauth

So far, I have my dotnetopenauth Provider and Relying installed and working on a server.  Great tool, however, the only 2.0 relying party site I can do an unsolicited assertion into is my own dotnetopenid relying party site.  Can someone give me an example of a 2.0 relying party site that will except a unsolicited assertion from dotnetopenauth OP.

I have tried many sites, Plaxo being one of them, there does not seem to be a list of Open ID 2.0 relying party sites.  Its hard to believe everyone is still on 1.1

---

Do you know of any who has done it correctly, is there a link in the world that I can test with besides my own.  I am working on a large scale project with my company.  I have used your op server and integrated into 2 factor authentication with a successful assertion into my RP.  But I would like a site that this process work's with outside of my own to prove your programs worth.

I can't prove it without your help, can you help me find one site this will work with.  I understand your design, fantastic by the way, but I need to be able to use it in a manner that will prove worth to our company.  I am a large scale senior developer, however, I am flying solo on this project.

Anything you or your team could do would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Most RPs are (presumably and hopefully) using OpenID 2.0.  However, implementing everything correctly such that unsolicited assertions work is something that most RPs in my experience *don't* get right.  Even a DotNetOpenAuth RP must still manually wire up their realm discovery page with the appropriate XRDS document to work correctly.

So you're probably doing it right... and most everyone else is doing it wrong.  That said, the OpenID 2.0 spec doesn't actually document *how* unsolicited assertions should be sent.  That's sort of left out.  So DotNetOpenAuth does RP discovery to figure out where to send the unsolicited assertion to -- which if the RP holds true to the spec should *just work* but because most things appear to work with a broken RP discovery doc, and most folks don't test against unsolicited assertions, it goes unfixed in their sites.